# clear form when modal close button was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was trying to reset my form when a close button was clicked.
this is my script.

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    console.log($(this).find('#form6')[0].reset());
})
```

when i console this it returns `undefined`. but when i remove `[0].reset()` the console returns a `length:1`, `0:form#form6`, `prevObject:r.fn.init[div#modalForm.modal.fade]` but when i use 
`$('#form6')[0].reset()` on form submit it works.. dont know why it doesn't work on button close..

i have a modal form which when i click a function is called that will append a certain data to my select tag. but when i close the modal and reopen it the data that was prev called stayed on my select tag then the function again was called so what happen was the data from my select tag duplicates.

so i was trying to reset the form when my modal was close.

Comment: `reset()` doesn't return anything, so the `console.log()` behaviour there is expected. We'd need to see a more complete sample of your JS and HTML to understand what's going on here. However as you're selecting by id the `find()` is rather redundant; just select the element directly.

Comment: Is `$(this)` an ancestor to `'#form6'`? ... if not, then that won't work as `find()` looks amongst children

Comment: "it doesn't work" what do you mean by doesn't work? Also assuming ids are unique (as they **must be**) you could simply do `$('#form6')`

Comment: @LGSon $(this) was referring to my modal then inside it was my #form6

Comment: @LionSmith Do you need to clear only select tag ? does it have a default value?

Comment: @LGSon it doesn't have. the value of the select tag was from the database. i tried using this $(this).find('#myselectag').empty() and it work.. but i was wondering if there is a way to clear the whole form that the specific tag.

Comment: As already commented, we need to see a working sample.